# Decision tree with final decision being a linear regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-trees

Question:
I want to implement a decision tree with each leaf being a linear regression, does such a model exist (preferable in sklearn)?

**Example case 1:**

Mockup data is generated using the formula:

```
y = int(x) + x * 1.5
```

Which looks like:

[image]

I want to solve this using a decision tree where the final decision results in a linear formula. Something like:

1. 0 <= x < 1 -> y = 0 + 1.5 * x
2. 1 <= x < 2 -> y = 1 + 1.5 * x
3. 2 <= x < 3 -> y = 2 + 1.5 * x
4. etc.

Which I figured could best be done using a decision tree. I've done some googling and I thought the `DecisionTreeRegressor` from `sklearn.tree` could work, but that results in points being assigned a constant value in a range, as shown below:
[image]

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor

x = np.linspace(0, 5, 100)
y = np.array([int(i) for i in x]) + x * 1.5

x_train = np.linspace(0, 5, 10)
y_train = np.array([int(i) for i in x_train]) + x_train * 1.5

clf = DecisionTreeRegressor()
clf.fit(x_train.reshape((len(x_train), 1)), y_train.reshape((len(x_train), 1)))

y_result = clf.predict(x.reshape(len(x), 1))
plt.plot(x, y, label='actual results')
plt.plot(x, y_result, label='model predicts')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

**Example case 2:**
Instead of one input, there are two inputs: x1 and x2, output is computed by:

1. x1 = 0 -> y = 1 * x2
2. x1 = 1 -> y = 3 * x2 + 5
3. x1 = 6 -> y = -1 * x2 -4
4. else -> y = x2 * 20 - 100

[image]

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

def get_y(x1, x2):
    if x1 == 0:
        return x2
    if x1 == 1:
        return 3 * x2 + 5
    if x1 == 6:
        return - x2 - 4
    return x2 * 20 - 100

X_0 = [(0, random.random()) for _ in range(100)]
x2_0 = [i[1] for i in X_0]
y_0 = [get_y(i[0], i[1]) for i in X_0]
X_1 = [(1, random.random()) for _ in range(100)]
x2_1 = [i[1] for i in X_1]
y_1 = [get_y(i[0], i[1]) for i in X_1]
X_2 = [(6, random.random()) for _ in range(100)]
x2_2 = [i[1] for i in X_2]
y_2 = [get_y(i[0], i[1]) for i in X_2]
X_3 = [(random.randint(10, 100), random.random()) for _ in range(100)]
x2_3 = [i[1] for i in X_3]
y_3 = [get_y(i[0], i[1]) for i in X_3]
plt.scatter(x2_0, y_0, label='x1 = 0')
plt.scatter(x2_1, y_1, label='x1 = 1')
plt.scatter(x2_2, y_2, label='x1 = 6')
plt.scatter(x2_3, y_3, label='x1 not 0, 1 or 6')
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('x2')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

So my question is: does a decision tree with each leaf being a linear regression, exist?

Comment: For anybody interested, I've started working on a project to implement an algorhytm similar to the one described in @BenReiniger answer over at https://gitlab.com/nathan_vanthof/regression-tree-algorithm-with-linear-regression-models-in-each-leaf

Comment: Your updated question is more general: modeling a piecewise-linear function where the slopes can change, so they're really n different lines, not just the same line with discontinuities (as in the first example). Also, **please add a plot of the updated question**, currently the question is a mishmash of both askings, hence hard to understand. And presumably that should be 'x2' on the x-axis of the updated question, not 'x'.

Comment: @smci my question is: is there is an existing decision tree with the end leaf being a linear regression? The problem statement is just an example case (minimal replicable problem), changing the example case does not change the question.

Comment: @smci I've restructured my question, I hope it's clear the question did not change, only the example case I gave :)

Comment: I think you are looking for a **piecewise linear regression**. It does exactly what you need: break the space of *y* into segments of different lenght, and run a separate linear regression on each of those.

Comment: This method was researched in the 90s and I'm afraid that it wasn't very successful. Do a search on treed-regression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for **Linear Trees**.

**Linear Trees** differ from **Decision Trees** because they compute linear approximation (instead of constant ones) fitting simple Linear Models in the leaves.

For a project of mine, I developed [linear-tree](https://github.com/cerlymarco/linear-tree): *a python library to build Model Trees with Linear Models at the leaves.*

[image]

linear-tree is developed to be fully integrable with scikit-learn.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import *
from lineartree import LinearTreeRegressor, LinearTreeClassifier

# REGRESSION
regr = LinearTreeRegressor(base_estimator=LinearRegression())
regr.fit(X, y)

# CLASSIFICATION
clf = LinearTreeClassifier(base_estimator=RidgeClassifier())
clf.fit(X, y)
```

`LinearTreeRegressor` and `LinearTreeClassifier` are provided as scikit-learn `BaseEstimator`. They are wrappers that build a decision tree on the data fitting a linear estimator from `sklearn.linear_model`. All the models available in `sklearn.linear_model` can be used as linear estimators.

Compare Decision Tree with Linear Tree:

[image]

[image]

Comment: does this work on big big data/tree ? e.g. 1M leafs ? each leaf 80 feature ?

Comment: it can reach a max_depth of 20, but consider that linear trees usually converge faster than decision trees, i.e. less deep structures... the more you want to go deep or be precise in the splits, the higher the training time

Answer (score 8):

> I think the easiest way to do this would be to have a decision tree where the final decision results in a linear formula.

Setting aside whether this is actually easiest/best, this type of model does exist, usually called "model-based recursive partitioning".  See e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/78563/232706
There are several packages in R for this: `partyfit` (and the older simpler `party`), `mob`, `Cubist`; unfortunately, there don't seem to be any in Python yet.  [Here's a discussion](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/11647) on including it in sklearn, from mid-2018.

Comment: Thanks, I've implemented a simple version that works for my problem: https://gitlab.com/nathan_vanthof/regression-tree-algorithm-with-linear-regression-models-in-each-leaf

Answer (score 3):

**I would suggest using spline regression.** or some polynomial regression.

Why? what you are basically approximating is the (almost) step-wise function. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1220082/find-the-best-polynomial-approximation-of-the-piecewise-function)

More info in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)) and a great background introduction in [here](http://www.alatown.com/spline/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It does answer my question but I now realize I simplified it too much. I've added some further explanation on what I exactly need.

Answer (score 2):

Even after your update, I think Noah's hint to spline regression is the best way to approach the problem. Here is a brief example in R:

```
# Generate data
x <- -50:100
y <- 0.001*x^3
plot(x,y)
df = data.frame(y,x)

# Linear regression
reg_ols=lm(y~.,data=df)
pred_ols = predict(reg_ols, newdata=df)

# GAM with regression splines
library(gam)
reg_gam = gam(y~s(x,5), data=df)
pred_gam = predict(reg_gam, newdata=df)

# Plot prediction and actual data
require(ggplot2)
df2 = data.frame(x,y,pred_ols, pred_gam)
ggplot(df2, aes(x)) +                    
  geom_line(aes(y=y),size=1, colour="red") +  
  geom_line(aes(y=pred_ols),size=1, colour="blue") +
  geom_line(aes(y=pred_gam),size=1, colour="black", linetype = "dashed")
```

So I have some function which is the data generating process (red line in the plot) and I want to get a good fit on this function. OLS (linear regression) will not work well (blue line in plot) but a GAM with splines will fit very well (black dashed).

[image]

This model looks like $y_i=\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{1,i} + u_i$ (so 2D-like), but of course you can expand the model to $y_i=\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{1,i} + ... + \beta_k x_{k,i} + u_i$, where $k$ is the number of "variables" in the model (so kD-like).

Since you seem to be on Python, you would need to look for a Py implementation of GAMs, such as [Statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/gam.html) of [PyGAM](https://github.com/dswah/pyGAM).

Chapter 7 of "Introduction to Statistical Learning" covers splines regression. You may have a look at the [Python Lab](https://github.com/a-martyn/ISL-python) for [the book](http://faculty.marshall.usc.edu/gareth-james/ISL/ISLR%20Seventh%20Printing.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Create a **new column** based on your formula and train your decision tree.
Then, based on the outcome class of the tree, pass the data to different regression.

This would be a sort of **Stacking**.[image]

Please treat this just an engineering approach, it might not be a good solution based on your data and need.